# Combine (union) data from multiple sources

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Can you help me solve this issue?

1. Create SQL view that will combine (union) data from multiple sources, and rename fields to match SSAS. The assumption is that the data is in the same database.

2.In the SQL view itself apply security, either using database row level security and simply a where clause if username = this then show this source.

How i can create this sql view?

Any input is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589294/creating-view-in-sqlserver

Comment: If it uses integrated security (if it is a webapp you should also configure it to impersonate) you could create whe view with a proper where. [SQL Server's current_user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: let me check thanks for input

Comment: This is just union of two different tables . I am having five tables having same column names. If i am going to use cubevalue function in excel then always i need to give reference of table name.